# How to implement php mb_substr() in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

PHP:

```
mb_substr("SERVICIOS INFORMÁTICOS", 0, 40)
```

javascript:

```
?
```

I'm working with xml file on nodejs. When I get a value in node and substring, The encoding has changed, and different value has been provided.  Is there a function that I can use like  mb_substr("SERVICIOS INFORMÁTICOS", 0, 40) in nodejs?

Comment: Instead of trying to think how to migrate a concept from one language to another, try to phrase your question as "I have data XYZ and I want to get XY. When I do `foo()` however, it gives me ABC."

Comment: Yes, but  when i get a value from xml file encoding has changed in nodejs,  It is a  serious problem for me. because I need to get and sign on this value. if value has changed, sign has been failure.

Comment: I understand. Please post actual code that you are using, what you expect/want it to be doing and what it is doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "SERVICIOS INFORMÁTICOS";
var res = str.substr(0, 40);

console.log(res);
```

try yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/48tm0xeu/